# Yosemite Installation Error

Tags: macos

[image]

Okay, so every time I install Yosemite on my iMac, it gives me the same response. I delete the copy, and reinstall it, but it still gives me the same error...

Comment: You may want to try running a disk verification to make sure you don't have any issues with your hard drive that could be causing the error

Comment: I have, nothing is wrong with the hard drive. Are there any other websites that provide a clean installation of Yosemite? It's either that, or no Yosemite for me...

Comment: Have you tried any possible fixes on Google, such as http://www.needhelp4mac.com/2014/10/this-copy-of-the-install-os-x-yosemite-application-cant-be-verified-it-may-have-been-corrupted-or-tampered-with-during-downloading/ ?

Comment: I've tried some, but none have helped so far... I'll try that Website, however.

Comment: Do check the validity of your Yosemite download, in Terminal paste following "shasum /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg" after waiting for a minute or so it will come up with a answer "4b93ff2cef88220a116fbce7c5707c9c57442bd0  /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg"

Comment: I'll try that if http://www.needhelp4mac.com/2014/10/this-copy-of-the-install-os-x-yosemite-application-cant-be-verified-it-may-have-been-corrupted-or-tampered-with-during-downloading/ doesn't work out for me, thank you!

Comment: Neither of the two have worked for me. As for shasum... I did that, with no response at all...

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy the installer of a drive? If you did, it's no good, as it will only work on the Mac that installed it. You will have to download the installer from the Mac App Store on the specific iMac you wish to install it on.

Comment: Okay. This is what I do. I go to the iMac's App Store, and I install Yosemite. When it's installed, I go to the Launchpad and look for the Yosemite. I open the Yosemite installer, then the error shows up. I delete, and re-do the entire process over again. In the Apple's forums, I asked the same thing, and someone answered to either download Yosemite from some other website (Third-party) or to report it to Apple's Service. Now, I don't want to pay for something that might be so obvious, so I'm hoping that the solution would be easily solved by doing something!